# Which javascript framework works best in mobile app development

Tags: android, reactjs, tabris-js

I want to know about for the native app development which framework should i choose 
Reactjs or Tabrisjs.

Please explain the advantage and disadvantage of both the frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through [Reactjs Advantage](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/mobile/react-native-hybrid-app-development/)

For mobile app development, you can also use [Meteor: Build Apps with JavaScript](https://www.meteor.com/)

Performance and UI-Design these two are the key component of mobile app development.

I went through these two:

**Performance**

I personally prefer React.

Reactjs, the web version, uses the dom so it requires a webview to run in native environments. This means that any transition, any animation, any interaction will happen as fast as it can happen on a webview. The web isn't as fast as native - yet, at this moment, for a while.. I don't know -

Getting started with Tabris.js is somewhat easier since the Tabris.js developer apps (that you install on your mobile device), save you from having to mess about with Xcode, provisioning profiles, Android SDKs and such. To be honest, I am not sure on what support React native has for Windows development.

With Tabris.js you can be running native code that you wrote, on your device, in 5 mins - you can use Windows, Mac, Linux, Whatever... Basically you need an internet connection, a mobile device, and a text editor. - [advocate @ Tabris.js](https://www.quora.com/For-a-new-mobile-app-what-we-should-use-React-Native-or-Tabris-js-Im-on-Windows-10)

**Design**

The tools for design methodology is similar in all respective. you can achieve it.

Comment: Okay but what about tabris.js?

Comment: check my updates